# Is there a more concise way to duplicate Kotlin objects that contain a "quantity" parameter?

Tags: list, kotlin

I have a `List` of objects that contain a `quantity` field and another field. I need to map these into a single `List` consisting of the other field, repeated `quantity` times.

For example, converting `[Pair("A", 1), Pair("B", 2)]` into `["A", "B", "B"]`.

Here's my attempt, which works, but contains both a `flatMap` and a `map`, and isn't particularly straightforward. I'm sure there's a very obvious Kotlin operator I'm missing, as this seems like a common use case!

```
listOfObjects.flatMap { myObject ->
    (0 until myObject.quantity).map {
        myObject.code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for

```
listOfObjects.flatMap { myObject -> List(myObject.quantity) { myObject.code } }
```